# Sort the contents of table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, datatable

I've the following tables created in MATLAB.

```
Tleft = table(['1'; '2'; "Node9"; "Node10"; ],...
            ["Node9"; "Node10"; '2'; '3';],...
            'VariableNames', {'h', 't'})
Tright = table(['1'; '2'; "Node9"; "Node10"; ],...
        ["Node9"; "Node10"; '2'; '3';],...
        [1;2;3;3],...
        'VariableNames', {'h', 't','value'})
```

I'm trying to sort the rows of `Tright` in the order of rows present in `Tleft`.

```
T = innerjoin(Tleft,Tright)
```

Expected result:

```
T =

  4×3 table

       h           t        value
    ________    ________    _____

    "1"         "Node9"       1  
    "2"         "Node10"      2  
    "Node9"     "2"           3  
    "Node10"    "3"           3
```

Result obtained:

```
T =


  4×3 table

       h           t        value
    ________    ________    _____

    "1"         "Node9"       1  
    "2"         "Node10"      2  
    "Node10"    "3"           3  
    "Node9"     "2"           3
```

Any suggestions on how to obtain the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obtained result is caused by sorting by `innerjoin`. One thing you could do is pad each `"Node9"` with a 0 (i.e., `"Node09"`) when creating your tables.

If that is not an option, you could consider using [sort_nat](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort_nat-natural-order-sort) (or any other similar sorting method from File Exchange) and sort `T` like:

```matlab
[~, index] = sort_nat(T.h);
T(index,:);
```